# How to correctly deserialize tuple property that has a default assignment?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class with a property of type `Tuple<int, int>`, which is assigned the default value `(-1, -1)`. I also have a json string representing an object of that class with non-default value assigned to the tuple property. 
When I am trying to deserialize the json string using Json.NET, the returned object's property has default values. 
If I remove the property default assignment in the class definition, the json string is correctly deserialized. 
This seems to happen only with properties of type Tuple. I tried with a string property for example, and had no issues deserializing non-default values.

How can I correctly deserialize a tuple property that has a default value? Is this a bug I should report on Json.NET?

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public Tuple<int, int> TuplePropertyWithDefault { get; set; } = new Tuple<int, int>(-1, -1);
        public string StringPropertyWithDefault { get; set; } = "";
        public Tuple<int, int> TuplePropertyWithoutDefault { get; set; }
        public string StringPropertyWithoutDefault { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"TuplePropertyWithDefault = {TuplePropertyWithDefault}\n" +
                    $"TuplePropertyWithoutDefault = {TuplePropertyWithoutDefault}\n" +
                    $"StringPropertyWithDefault = {StringPropertyWithDefault}\n" +
                    $"StringPropertyWithoutDefault = {StringPropertyWithoutDefault}\n";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var expected = new MyClass();
            expected.TuplePropertyWithDefault = new Tuple<int, int> (0, 0);
            expected.TuplePropertyWithoutDefault = new Tuple<int, int> (0, 0);

            expected.StringPropertyWithDefault = "test";
            expected.StringPropertyWithoutDefault = "test";

            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expected).ToString();

            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonString);

            Console.WriteLine("Expected:");
            Console.WriteLine(expected);
            Console.WriteLine("Deserialized:");
            Console.WriteLine(deserialized);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Targetting .Net Framework 4.7.2, and using Newtonsoft.Json version 12.0.2.

Comment: "*(Will provide sample code shortly)*" -- why not do that **before** posting the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* this is because Json.NET expects POCO sub-objects to be standard mutable classes, but the `Tuple<...>` family is *immutable*.

Frankly, `Tuple<...>` is a bad choice here *anyway* because of naming, so: you probably *can* configure yourself out of this scenario by spending lots of time writing custom code for Json.NET, but... it would seem more pragmatic and sensible to just *declare your own POCO* that has suitable properties.

As a side note: value-tuples are mutable and seem to work in the way you would expect, but: I don't think they would make a good choice here, for the same naming reasons, plus others.